# How do I cite a technical report in End Note?

Tags: reference-managers, tools

I'm using End Note as a references manager for my thesis. I'm wondering how do I reference a technical report since End Note gives no option for it. It has books, articles, patents, etc. but no technical reports.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the option that is closest to what you want, e.g. report, article, document.